# Paytm integration shows white screen while click on login/sign up and Shows error if try to pay with Debit card

Tags: android

I have follow [this example](https://github.com/Paytm-Payments/Paytm_Android_App_Kit) to integrate the paytm in android and also generated successfully CHECKSUMHASH.

But when click on login to complete my payment it shows me white blank screen and here is the log of that

```
    01-03 16:34:50.686 22910-23538/com.example.merchantapp I/VideoCapabilities: Unsupported profile 4 for video/mp4v-es
01-03 16:34:51.909 22910-22910/com.example.merchantapp I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(0)] "The SSL certificate used to load resources from https://static3.paytm.in will be distrusted in the future. Once distrusted, users will be prevented from loading these resources. See https://g.co/chrome/symantecpkicerts for more information.", source: https://pguat.paytm.com/oltp-web/processTransaction (0)
01-03 16:34:52.566 22910-22910/com.example.merchantapp I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(0)] "The SSL certificate used to load resources from https://accounts-uat.paytm.com will be distrusted in the future. Once distrusted, users will be prevented from loading these resources. See https://g.co/chrome/symantecpkicerts for more information.", source: about:blank (0)
01-03 16:34:52.571 22910-22910/com.example.merchantapp I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(0)] "The SSL certificate used to load resources from https://accounts-uat.paytm.com will be distrusted in the future. Once distrusted, users will be prevented from loading these resources. See https://g.co/chrome/symantecpkicerts for more information.", source: https://accounts-uat.paytm.com/oauth2/authorize?response_type=code&scope=paytm&theme=pg&redirect_uri=https://pguat.paytm.com/oltp-web/oauthResponse&ADDRESS1=&ADDRESS2=&state=plmoknijb852:amitgo59443067266036:70000515503:WAP:9DA18B87DE166C589E3670A8228B0A31.amitgo59443067266036plmoknijb852.webjvm1:AUTO:908773715:webjvm1&client_id=testclient&device=mobile (0)
01-03 16:34:54.808 22910-22910/com.example.merchantapp I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(566)] "Uncaught ReferenceError: angular is not defined", source: https://accounts-uat.paytm.com/oauth2/authorize?response_type=code&scope=paytm&theme=pg&redirect_uri=https://pguat.paytm.com/oltp-web/oauthResponse&ADDRESS1=&ADDRESS2=&state=plmoknijb852:amitgo59443067266036:70000515503:WAP:9DA18B87DE166C589E3670A8228B0A31.amitgo59443067266036plmoknijb852.webjvm1:AUTO:908773715:webjvm1&client_id=testclient&device=mobile (566)
01-03 16:34:54.853 22910-22910/com.example.merchantapp D/PGSDK: Page finished loading https://pguat.paytm.com/oltp-web/processTransaction
01-03 16:34:54.858 22910-22910/com.example.merchantapp D/PGSDK: Progress dialog ended
01-03 16:34:54.997 22910-22910/com.example.merchantapp I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(0)] "The SSL certificate used to load resources from https://static4.paytm.in will be distrusted in the future. Once distrusted, users will be prevented from loading these resources. See https://g.co/chrome/symantecpkicerts for more information.", source: https://pguat.paytm.com/oltp-web/processTransaction (0)
01-03 16:35:08.181 22910-22910/com.example.merchantapp I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(994)] "Unable to preventDefault inside passive event listener due to target being treated as passive. See https://www.chromestatus.com/features/5093566007214080", source: https://static3.paytm.in/1.4/js/zepto-1.1.3.js?v=1509447554886 (994)
01-03 16:35:08.181 22910-23429/com.example.merchantapp E/chromium: [ERROR:service_manager.cc(157)] Connection InterfaceProviderSpec prevented service: content_renderer from binding interface: blink::mojom::ReportingServiceProxy exposed by: content_browser
01-03 16:35:08.285 22910-22910/com.example.merchantapp D/PGSDK: Page started loading https://accounts-uat.paytm.com/oauth2/authorize?response_type=code&scope=paytm&theme=pg&redirect_uri=https://pguat.paytm.com/oltp-web/oauthResponse&ADDRESS1=&ADDRESS2=&state=plmoknijb852:amitgo59443067266036:70000515503:WAP:9DA18B87DE166C589E3670A8228B0A31.amitgo59443067266036plmoknijb852.webjvm1:MANUAL:908773715:webjvm1&client_id=testclient&device=mobile
01-03 16:35:08.285 22910-22910/com.example.merchantapp D/PGSDK: Progress dialog started
01-03 16:35:08.460 22910-22910/com.example.merchantapp D/PGSDK: Page finished loading https://accounts-uat.paytm.com/oauth2/authorize?response_type=code&scope=paytm&theme=pg&redirect_uri=https://pguat.paytm.com/oltp-web/oauthResponse&ADDRESS1=&ADDRESS2=&state=plmoknijb852:amitgo59443067266036:70000515503:WAP:9DA18B87DE166C589E3670A8228B0A31.amitgo59443067266036plmoknijb852.webjvm1:MANUAL:908773715:webjvm1&client_id=testclient&device=mobile
01-03 16:35:08.460 22910-22910/com.example.merchantapp D/PGSDK: Progress dialog ended
01-03 16:35:08.460 22910-22910/com.example.merchantapp D/PGSDK: Page started loading https://accounts-uat.paytm.com/oauth2/authorize?response_type=code&scope=paytm&theme=pg&redirect_uri=https://pguat.paytm.com/oltp-web/oauthResponse&ADDRESS1=&ADDRESS2=&state=plmoknijb852:amitgo59443067266036:70000515503:WAP:9DA18B87DE166C589E3670A8228B0A31.amitgo59443067266036plmoknijb852.webjvm1:MANUAL:908773715:webjvm1&client_id=testclient&device=mobile
01-03 16:35:08.460 22910-22910/com.example.merchantapp D/PGSDK: Progress dialog started
01-03 16:35:08.725 22910-22910/com.example.merchantapp I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(0)] "The SSL certificate used to load resources from https://accounts-uat.paytm.com will be distrusted in the future. Once distrusted, users will be prevented from loading these resources. See https://g.co/chrome/symantecpkicerts for more information.", source: https://pguat.paytm.com/oltp-web/processTransaction (0)
01-03 16:35:08.754 22910-22910/com.example.merchantapp I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(0)] "The SSL certificate used to load resources from https://accounts-uat.paytm.com will be distrusted in the future. Once distrusted, users will be prevented from loading these resources. See https://g.co/chrome/symantecpkicerts for more information.", source: https://accounts-uat.paytm.com/oauth2/authorize?response_type=code&scope=paytm&theme=pg&redirect_uri=https://pguat.paytm.com/oltp-web/oauthResponse&ADDRESS1=&ADDRESS2=&state=plmoknijb852:amitgo59443067266036:70000515503:WAP:9DA18B87DE166C589E3670A8228B0A31.amitgo59443067266036plmoknijb852.webjvm1:MANUAL:908773715:webjvm1&client_id=testclient&device=mobile (0)
01-03 16:35:10.970 22910-22910/com.example.merchantapp I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(566)] "Uncaught ReferenceError: angular is not defined", source: https://accounts-uat.paytm.com/oauth2/authorize?response_type=code&scope=paytm&theme=pg&redirect_uri=https://pguat.paytm.com/oltp-web/oauthResponse&ADDRESS1=&ADDRESS2=&state=plmoknijb852:amitgo59443067266036:70000515503:WAP:9DA18B87DE166C589E3670A8228B0A31.amitgo59443067266036plmoknijb852.webjvm1:MANUAL:908773715:webjvm1&client_id=testclient&device=mobile (566)
01-03 16:35:10.973 22910-22910/com.example.merchantapp D/PGSDK: Page finished loading https://accounts-uat.paytm.com/oauth2/authorize?response_type=code&scope=paytm&theme=pg&redirect_uri=https://pguat.paytm.com/oltp-web/oauthResponse&ADDRESS1=&ADDRESS2=&state=plmoknijb852:amitgo59443067266036:70000515503:WAP:9DA18B87DE166C589E3670A8228B0A31.amitgo59443067266036plmoknijb852.webjvm1:MANUAL:908773715:webjvm1&client_id=testclient&device=mobile
01-03 16:35:10.973 22910-22910/com.example.merchantapp D/PGSDK: Progress dialog ended
```

And when I am trying to pay via Debit card it shows the following information on screen:

```
Failure of Web Server bridge:
No backend server available for connection:
time out after 10 seconds or idempotent set to OFF or method not implemented
```

If anyone can help me for this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hope I am not late to post answer for this question.

To use paytm sdk you will need uniq **“ORDER_ID”** otherwise your payment will get error.

Make sure you have correct **“CALLBACK_URL”** you can set the below one : **https://pguat.paytm.com/paytmchecksum/paytmCallback.jsp**

Also note that you pass the same parameters in **PaytmOrder** which you have passed to generate **checksum** [you can refer the project](https://github.com/Sameer-Jani-201/PayTMDemo).

Comment: @Rozina
Sure mate,happy to Help:)